# angular provider $get doubts

Tags: angularjs, provider

I have some doubts about providers. 
Can someone explain me why I cannot access from the controller the "setText" provider function? 
I can only access functions inside the $get block.

```
var myMod = angular.module('myApp', []);

myMod.controller("mainCtrl", [ "$scope","greeting", function($scope, greeting){
    greetingProvider.setText("Hi, ");
}]);

myMod.provider('greeting', function() {
  var text = 'Hello, ';

  this.setText = function(value) {
    text = value;
  };

  this.$get = function() {
    return function(name) {
      console.log(text + name);
    };
  };
});

myMod.config(function(greetingProvider) {
  greetingProvider.setText("Howdy there, ");
});

myMod.run(function(greeting) {
  greeting('Ford Prefect');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `setText` function is only exposed on your app.config. The only thing you'll have when you access the provider within your controller is what you've included inside the $get function.

For a more detailed answer, check this article:

http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

Answer (score 0):

Providers are accessible only in configuration phase of application life cycle. Their specific purpose is to provide a way to configure the future service, which provider should return via `this.$get` method.

In your case it doesn't really feel like you need a provider, simple service (factory) would have been enough. Or your can make use of factory and add one more method `set` to change `text` variable, stored in closure.